# Kafka KStream - significant startup delay

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Im running into an issue with my **KStreams** based application: it will run once and when I stop/restart it gets 'stuck' and won't progress anymore until I delete the various topics it has created. This doesn't happen *every* time but more often than not.

Typically this happens when I copy a new(er) version to the work VM (in the same subnet as the kafka cluster for speed reasons).

When it's wedged I'll see;

1. "Connect":  `org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection`
2. "Client": `[StreamThread-1] INFO   o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamTask - Creating restoration consumer client`
3. "Ping" : I'll see these and the app won't shut down normally. It must be kill'd.

In any of these cases the message will typically repeat indefinitely (well - at least all the way through a lunch + meeting. IE Too long).

The app is shutting down 'cleanly' before this happens.

What am I doing wrong?

---

### Edit:

This most recent time - after 20 minutes I got a stream of errors:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 101 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers

followed by:

> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member

--> which is a good trick since there *is no other member*.

Comment: Quite odd. Which version of Kafka is that?

Comment: Latest release from Confluent.io. 3.0.1 I believe.

Comment: If it is Confluent 3.0.1, this means you're running Kafka 0.10.0.1 -- thus see Guozhang Wang's answer below, which might be the problem you are facing.  This might be the case particularly if you are operating in a somewhat "slow" environment (your past SO questions indicate that you had some such woes previously).

Answer (score 2):

If you are running with Kafka 0.10.0.x then you may be hitting a known issue:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread

This has been resolved in the upcomming 0.10.1.0 release of Kafka, and I would recommend you trying out the new version to see if this issue goes away.

Comment: Ive upgraded to 0.10.1.0. Still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm, this is a bit wired, and we have not seen similar scenarios in our testing environment yet. Do you mind creating a JIRA with the most-recent observed log traces to Apache Kafka so I can better help investigating it.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA